# Использование шаблонов на сайте

Tags: php, шаблонизаторы, tpl

Погуглив, прочитав кучу статей, пришел к выводу, что использование шаблонов в моём случае было бы, скажем так, весьма кстати. Порывшись в нете, нашел `Smarty`, но по факту это движок. Значит, в принципе можно реализовывать всё самому. Нашел пару примеров через `ereg_replace()` и `str_replace()`. Но примеры слишком скудные по материалу. Собственно вопрос: как это делается, более конкретно, и как при использовании шаблонов получать необходимый в шаблоны материал?

Comment: Шаблоны обязательно без участия php? ex.: `<?=cblock('news', 'main_template')?>`

ЗЫ: Смарти - зло. Если у вас нет нагрузки ~3-4 визитки в день и вы не работаете с 2 верстальщиками, которые знакомы только со Смарти - он *не нужен*.

Comment: проблема в том, что я один занимаюсь написанием сайта, уже на 3 раза менял и код пхп и менял 4 раза шаблон.. при этом соответственно приходилось заново писать всю структуру, что уж очень утомительно. пораскинув мозгами по асфальту... пришел к выводу, что хочу сделать отдельно мозг, отдельно "дизайн". чтобы в случае необходимости не приходилось менять всё, из за необходимости к примеру сменить шаблон сайта. ну как то так...

Comment: Лучше делать как пока получается, ато можно переделывать нацать раз и зависнуть так ничего не сделав! Если проет делается только для себя и студент верстальщик не всунит туда свой нос, то как по мне нас...ать на сколько код красивый! Но нас...ать первое время! А для усоввершенствования нужно иметь хоть что-то! "Первые BMW тоже не ездили 350 км/ч"

Comment: это всё понятно, у нас вообще проект как то замер... начали очень активно, и через полгода всё встало(на 2 года), сейчас опять оплатили домен... и тд и тп.. на меня опять повесили веб часть проекта, первые пару месяцев вообще сидел читал свой код, мысли "господи как я такое мог навоять" элементарная регистрация даже не проверяла наличие имени пользователя в базе, опять сменил шаблон, переписав чуть больше половины кода... понял, что больше если что так встрять не хочу.

Answer (score 1):

Php сам по себе является шаблонизатором. Просто не стоит использовать в шаблоне логику больше, чем `<? if : ?> <? else : ?> <? endif; ?>` и можно сократить вывод до `<?= $var; ?>`. Посмотрите, как сделаны серьезные фреймворки (`Zend Framework`, `Symfony`) - там в шаблонах используется `native php` + хэлперы, и никакого мусора нет.

Comment: в 5 утра что то лень сидеть в нетах, искать) можно линк в студию на фреймворки?

Answer (score 0):

Шаблонизатор получится написать тогда, когда возмешься его писать! Гуглить в поисках шаблонизатора нет смысла, так как примеры и готовые решения дохлые, на серьезном проекте с них толку нет! Что касательно `Smarty` - сильно увесисто. Да и я лично плюсов ему не отдаю! Для того, чтобы создать хотя бы на свое мнение хороший шаблонизатор, нужно чухать Объектно-ориентированное программирование (ООП). Почухивать можно начать вот тут! [Classes and Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) На первое время можно обойтись тем же `ereg_replace()` и `str_replace()`. Сам так начинал юзать, главное - понять суть работы, а потом уже искать объективную замену!

Comment: ereg - deprecated, забывайте про него потихоньку.

Comment: Я уже забыл, взято исключительно из вопроса)

Comment: Ну, примерно, я представляю, что это за пару вечеров не напишешь. Интересует общая структура, может быть есть хорошие мануалы по этому делу. Конечно, можно взять тот же bb'шный форум и его расковырять, но я жуть как не люблю ковырять чужие творения, особенно без комментариев.
По факту у меня сейчас где-то 200 файлов .php на сайте, для каждого отдельного момента, общий .css соответственно. и не дай бог я подумаю, что мне не нравиться текущий шаблон. Придется, хорошо если только править все эти файлы...

Comment: Как вариант, посмотрите как реализовано отображение в известных фреймворках аля `Zend`, `Cake` etc.<br>
И разобравшись примерно как, что и куда, просто пишите свою реализацию.